# SQL Server Query - Problems with Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written the following SQL query to return a set of results for a report.

However, due to my lack of knowledge I am struggling with the where clause. I only need to see the results for buildings (BLDGCODE) where a building has:

sum of CAPACITY in a bldg / sum of OCCUPANCY in a bldg < 0.75

Can anyone help and finish this for me?

```
SELECT 
distinct (RTRIM(FME1.DESCRIP)) AS REGION, 
RTRIM(FME2.DESCRIP) AS COUNTRY, 
RTRIM(FMLS.SITEDESC) AS SITE, 
RTRIM(FMB0.BLDGCODE) AS BLDGCODE, 
rtrim(fmb0.bldgdesc) as BLDGDESC, 
RTRIM(FMEZ.PROPTYPE) AS [PROPERTY TYPE], 
rtrim(fma0.floorcode) as FLOORCODE, 

(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-TLS-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-VACU-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-VACM-AS' THEN 0 
        ELSE FMA0.RENTABLE END) AS [CHARGEABLE AREA], 

(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-TLS-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-VACU-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-VACM-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'X-XXEXTW' OR 
        RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) like '%BC' OR 
        RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) like '%FC' OR 
        RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) like '%VP' THEN 0 
        ELSE FMA0.AREA END) AS [NET INT AREA], 

(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-TLS-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-VACU-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'U-VACM-AS' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE = 'X-XXEXTW' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'U-CAF%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'U-FC%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'U-LO%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'U-MFR%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'U-RANODSK%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'U-SEC%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'EQ-%' OR 
        RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) like '%BC' OR 
        RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) like '%FC' OR 
        RTRIM(FMA0.SPACETYPE) like '%VP' THEN 0 
        ELSE FMA0.AREA END) AS [FLOOR NET INT AREA], 

ISNULL(rtrim(fmg0.group_),'0000') as [COST CODE], 

isnull(RTRIM(FMG0.GROUPDESC),'Unassigned Space') AS [COST CENTRE], 

(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-OFF-%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-WKS-%' THEN FMA0.CAPACITY 
        ELSE 0 END) AS CAPACITY, 

(CASE WHEN (FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-OFF-%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-WKS-%') AND FMA0.CAPACITY = 1 AND FMA0.OCC_MAN > 0 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OCCUPANCY, 

(CASE WHEN FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-OFF-%' OR 
        FMA0.SPACETYPE like 'A-WKS-%' THEN FMA0.OCC_MAN 
        ELSE 0 END)AS HEAD_COUNT, 

fma0.spacetype as [SPACETYPE], 
FMA0.RMID 

FROM fmB0 
LEFT JOIN FMLS ON FMB0.SITECODE = FMLS.SITECODE 
LEFT JOIN FME2 ON FME2.CNTRY_CODE = FMLS.CNTRY_CODE 
LEFT JOIN FME1 ON FME1.REG_CODE = FMB0.REG_CODE 
LEFT JOIN FMA0 ON FMA0.BLDGCODE = FMB0.BLDGCODE 
left join fmas on fma0.group_=fmas.group_ 
left join fmg0 on fma0.group_=fmg0.group_ 
left join fmez on fmb0.proptype=fmez.ez_key 
where
```

Comment: If you are talking about the `sum()` of various columns, I would expect a `group by` and aggregation functions in the `select`.

Comment: Plus `HAVING` clause for @GordonLinoff's comment